# Batch to pattern matching in a loop

Tags: batch-file, command-line

I am trying to loop through a file which contains few names and search the same with two patterns in another file and echo some statements.

Like I have two files :

1.Installers.txt
2.Progress.txt

1. Installers.txt

   ```
     abc.jar
      def.jar
      tef.jar
      ....
         ....
   ```
2. Progress.txt

   ```
      abc.jar deployment started
      abc.jar deployed successfully
      def.jar deployment started
   ```

So my requirement is to read the Installers.txt file one line at a time and search for the 2 patterns "abc.jar deployment started" and "abc.jar deployed successfully" and report successful or else if both patterns are yet to be found to show as still in progress.

I have tried writing below but its failing at many things while doing pattern and the logic also does not look good. can someone help here.

```
          for /F "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("Installer.txt") do (
   set /A i+=1
      call echo installing %%i%% : %%a
          :NOTVALID
       findstr /I "%%k\ in\ progress" %1%\progress.txt
              If errorlevel 1 (
              echo "installation still in progress.."
               PING 127.0.0.1 -n 1 >NUL 2>&1 || PING ::1 -n 1 >NUL 2>&1
              goto NOTVALID 
            ) else (
                  set /A i+=1
                  echo "installation completed.."

                call set array[%%i%%]=%%a
                 call set n=%%i%%
                  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code which suite your requirement :

```
 cls
@echo off
for /f %%g in (Installers.txt) do type Progress.txt|findstr "%%g" || echo %%g is Yet to start , still in progress
```

Above code will read a single line from installer and then search for that string in file Progress.txt and then print the output if it is found or not.